# translate the phrase "What should I eat to stay healthy?"

Tags: traducción, verbos, conjugación, preguntas

I am confused to what verb I should conjugate in this sentence. Should I translate this sentence to

> ¿Qué debo comer a mantenerse sano?

since "should" appears before "eat", or should I translate it to

> ¿Qué deber como a mantenerse sano?"

since "I" appears before the verb "eat"? If I made any extra mistakes, can you please inform me. I am very new to the Spanish language.

Thank you.

Comment: "Qué comer para mantenerse sano" is also correct. This formulation is more distant and general.

Answer (score 4):

I don't follow your two different rationales, but in any case the correct translation is:
Qué debo comer **para** mantener**me** sano?

Additional mistakes:

1. 'To' here means 'in order to', which is translated as 'para'. 
   'To' in the sense of 'towards' would be translated as 'a'.
2. Mantener**me** the reflexive is in the first person.

Answer (score 2):

***should*** is used to give advice. In this case, you're giving yourself an advice an not an obligation.
***Debo*** is for a personal obligation.

So, we have

> ¿Qué debería comer para mantenerme sano?
>    ¿Qué debería comer para quedarme sano? (Literal translation of the verb **stay**.)
>    ¿Qué debería comer para estar sano? (Most common way to say this.)

Note that by using **mantener**, we require to write **mantenerme** in order to specify who we are talking to.

> ¿Qué debería comer para mantener sano? (It shows the advice for oneself but it doesn't specify which part of the body to be healthy.)
>    ¿Qué debería comer para mantenerme sano? (It shows the advice for onself and specifies the whole body.)